# apply style on arabic text only

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint-2010

I have application which used telerik in sharepoint 2010
the text some time will be in arabic or english. Its depend on user.

here is the code, which I am trying to fetch the arabic.

```
var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
var string = document.getElementById('td').innerHTML.value; // some Arabic string from Wikipedia

alert(arabic.test(string)); // displays true
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Well put that code in a function so it checks whether a string is Arabic:

```
function isArabic(s) {
    var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
    return arabic.test(s);
}
```

Now get the text of the element you want to apply style on, if it returned true give it the style.

```
var elm = document.getElementById('td');
var str = elm.textContent; //or innerHTML or value if it's an input
if(isArabic(str))
    elm.style.background = 'red'; //whatever style you want
```

EDIT:
If you want to change the style of `tds` only then:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    var str = elms[i].textContent;
    if(isArabic(str)) {
        elms[i].style.background = 'green';
        elms[i].style.fontSize = '32px';
    }
    else {
        elms[i].style.background = 'blue';
        elms[i].style.fontSize = '12px';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but still no effect.
I m trying to attached the image so you get the point out where I am making mistake [link] http://faisaljanjua.com/x/2.jpg [link]http://faisaljanjua.com/x/1.jpg

Comment: Could you add the part that's not working to your question please? Attaching image as background?

Comment: so you just copy/pasted the code? if yes, then it'll only change background of an element with `id="td"` to red which I don't see any in your image. Do you just want to change the style of `td` elements? In that case you can use `getElementsByTagName()` instead of `getElementById()` and what style do you want to give them?

Comment: I tried even the 'TagName' but its not working, just to use font size: and font-family:

Comment: Check the edit. added else bit just for test, if it works just remove it.